# Radeon RX 460 graphics card and 4K monitor

Tags: graphics-card

I want to drive a 4K monitor using basic windows business apps (e.g. Excel)

My PC:  Intel i5-3570K processor; Gigabyte Motherboard (Z77X-UP4-TH); 32 GB RAM; running Windows 8.1 OS

Not interested in gaming, but specifically interested in cost effective large screen 4K display (most likely Samsung 43inch 4K monitor)

The new Radeon RX 460 looks like it will drive a 4K monitor at a reasonable price (Display port 1.4).

Am I missing anything, or will this just work?

Comment: It will work perfectly.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). You could try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Off topic or not, a  RX460 is overkill for what you're trying to do.  I have a GTX730 which does 4k just fine.  pay attention to the HDMI vs DisplayPort (and their versions) frame rates. typically HDMI only does 30fps where DP will do 60. on a desktop env a low end GPU will do 60FPS just fine though I doubt you'll care if all you're using is MS word.

Another option to consider is upgrading your CPU.  One generation newer on your cpu (intel iX-4XXX cpus can do 4K off the cpu.  Check Intel Ark for the various specs. http://ark.intel.com/products/75043/Intel-Core-i5-4570-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz